# Prevent Windows 10 Restart, Shutdown or Hibernate while backup process active

Tags: windows, backup, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Is there any way I can prevent all Windows users from accidentally shutting down a Windows 10 Pro machine by going to Win-Start Menu -> e.g. Restart, Shutdown or Hibernate and clicking on it while a process called backupprocess.exe is running?

I want to avoid corrupting a backup container that is being written to.

I've tried the following

Open the registry editor and navigate to the following key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
```

Change the value of NoClose to 1. If NoClose does not exist, create the DWORD value and set it to 1.

Restart Explorer to see the changes.

But that is the problem.

How can I automate this without having to restart Explorer to see the changes?  Even if I could automate to write to the registry, it's a bad user experience if Win-Explorer loses all open windows at that moment.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Put the restriction, *per* https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.StartMenu::NoClose , in a script that runs on user login, at least on the day backup is planned, and include restart of Explorer in that script. Of course, a user could still hold down he power button or yank the plug...

Comment: It is sometimes easier to teach a new behavior to a user, than it is to try to work around it. If it's not out of the question, maybe they can just check if the process is running themselves? Might be impossible, but I don't know what type of environment you are working in. I personally wouldn't want to change the default behavior of reboot and shutdown without some type of notification to the user to explain why buttons are not working. If the backup is fast, maybe it makes sense to suspend operation and wait for a user to log off or become idle before executing. GPO policies might help too.